# Can not save char data to xml file in MATLAB

Tags: java, xml, matlab, dom, svg

I want to modify xml text information of an svg file in MATLAB.
I renamed the svg file to xml file

```
    system('rename *myfile.svg* *myfile.xml')
```

got the XML text info:

```
    fid = fopen(‘myfile.xml');
    XMLdata = fscanf(fid, '%s');
```

XMLdata is a char array containing XML text info
Now I can modify the XMLdata using strcmp for eg:

```
    new_claim = strrep(XMLdata, 'Sans', 'Times New Roman')
```

Now I could not write this XMLdata to an xml file using xmlwrite

```
    xmlwrite('fileout.xml', XMLdata)
```

I am getting error

Error using javaMethod
Java exception occurred:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"standalone="no"?><!--CreatedwithInkscape(http://www.inkscape.org/)--><svgxmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"width="64"height="48"id="svg3033"version="1.1"inkscape:version="0.48.5r10040"sodipodi:docname="200mn.svg"><defsid="defs3035"/><sodipodi:namedviewid="base"pagecolor="#ffffff"bordercolor="#666666"borderopacity="1.0"inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"inkscape:pageshadow="2"inkscape:zoom="5.916495"inkscape:cx="61.898573"inkscape:cy="54.220135"inkscape:document-units="px"inkscape:current-layer="layer1"showgrid="false"inkscape:window-width="1280"inkscape:window-height="962"inkscape:window-x="-8"inkscape:window-y="-8"inkscape:window-maximized="1"/><metadataid="metadata3038"><rdf:RDF><cc:Workrdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:typerdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><ginkscape:label="Layer1"inkscape:groupmode="layer"id="layer1"transform="translate(0,-1004.3622)"><textxml:space="preserve"style="font-size:28px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Calibri;-inkscape-font-specification:Calibri"x="1.3270224e-007"y="1035.7983"id="text3049"sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspansodipodi:role="line"id="tspan3051"x="1.3270224e-007"y="1035.7983">200m</tspan></text></g></svg>

    at com.icl.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:92)

    at com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.serializeXML(XMLUtils.java:175)

    at com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.serializeXML(XMLUtils.java:44)

Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"standalone="no"?><!--CreatedwithInkscape(http://www.inkscape.org/)--><svgxmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"width="64"height="48"id="svg3033"version="1.1"inkscape:version="0.48.5r10040"sodipodi:docname="200mn.svg"><defsid="defs3035"/><sodipodi:namedviewid="base"pagecolor="#ffffff"bordercolor="#666666"borderopacity="1.0"inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"inkscape:pageshadow="2"inkscape:zoom="5.916495"inkscape:cx="61.898573"inkscape:cy="54.220135"inkscape:document-units="px"inkscape:current-layer="layer1"showgrid="false"inkscape:window-width="1280"inkscape:window-height="962"inkscape:window-x="-8"inkscape:window-y="-8"inkscape:window-maximized="1"/><metadataid="metadata3038"><rdf:RDF><cc:Workrdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:typerdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><ginkscape:label="Layer1"inkscape:groupmode="layer"id="layer1"transform="translate(0,-1004.3622)"><textxml:space="preserve"style="font-size:28px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Calibri;-inkscape-font-specification:Calibri"x="1.3270224e-007"y="1035.7983"id="text3049"sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspansodipodi:role="line"id="tspan3051"x="1.3270224e-007"y="1035.7983">200m</tspan></text></g></svg>

at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)

at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)

at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown
Source)

at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)

at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)

at com.icl.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:90)

... 2 more
```

---

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="UTF-8"standalone="no"?><!--CreatedwithInkscape(http://www.inkscape.org/)--><svgxmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"width="64"height="48"id="svg3033"version="1.1"inkscape:version="0.48.5r10040"sodipodi:docname="200mn.svg"><defsid="defs3035"/><sodipodi:namedviewid="base"pagecolor="#ffffff"bordercolor="#666666"borderopacity="1.0"inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"inkscape:pageshadow="2"inkscape:zoom="5.916495"inkscape:cx="61.898573"inkscape:cy="54.220135"inkscape:document-units="px"inkscape:current-layer="layer1"showgrid="false"inkscape:window-width="1280"inkscape:window-height="962"inkscape:window-x="-8"inkscape:window-y="-8"inkscape:window-maximized="1"/><metadataid="metadata3038"><rdf:RDF><cc:Workrdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:typerdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/><dc:title></dc:title></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><ginkscape:label="Layer1"inkscape:groupmode="layer"id="layer1"transform="translate(0,-1004.3622)"><textxml:space="preserve"style="font-size:28px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Calibri;-inkscape-font-specification:Calibri"x="1.3270224e-007"y="1035.7983"id="text3049"sodipodi:linespacing="125%"><tspansodipodi:role="line"id="tspan3051"x="1.3270224e-007"y="1035.7983">200m</tspan></text></g></svg>

    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown
    Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)

    at com.icl.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:90)

    at com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.serializeXML(XMLUtils.java:175)

    at com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.serializeXML(XMLUtils.java:44)


Error in xmlwrite (line 83)
javaMethod('serializeXML',...
```

Comment: I don't have any experience using `xmlwrite`, but looking at [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlwrite.html) it doesn't seem like it accepts a string input.

Comment: @excaza you are correct, is there any method to write an xml file with that modified char datatype 'new_claim'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlwrite` is a partner function to `xmlread` and works with a Document Object Model node. If all you want to do is some simple string replacement you could do something like this:

```
filename = 'myfile.svg';
XMLdata = fileread(filename);

new_claim = strrep(XMLdata, 'Sans', 'Times New Roman');

fid = fopen(filename, 'w+');
fwrite(fid, new_claim);
fclose(fid);
```

There is no need to rename the file. `fileread` just reads a file into a string. `strrep` returns the modified string, so it is actually `new_claim` that you'd want to save to a file. As you're just working with a string, `fwrite` can be used to save the new string to file.

Comment: It works very well.With this code, I am able able to replace the the font in SVG file.Thank you

Comment: That's great, I'm glad it worked. If this does solve your problem perhaps you could mark it as the answer?

Comment: Can you please tell me any solution to view this svg file in MATLAB as a figure

Comment: I think that's the subject of a new question. Don't forget to include a sample of your svg file in your question either as a download hosted on an external site or paste a shorted version of the file contents into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that all spaces (or line breaks) seem to have been removed from your `.svg`, and so the XML tags aren't recognized properly (e.g.: instead of `<svg xmlns ...` you have `<svgxmlns ...` which is supposed to be closed by `</svg>` etc.)

It seems to be ok after adding the spaces\breaks where needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!--CreatedwithInkscape(http://www.inkscape.org/)-->
<svg 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
    width="64"
    height="48"
    id="svg3033"
    version="1.1"
    inkscape:version="0.48.5r10040"
    sodipodi:docname="200mn.svg">
    <defs
        id="defs3035"/>
    <sodipodi:namedview
        id="base"
        pagecolor="#ffffff"
        bordercolor="#666666"
        borderopacity="1.0"
        inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
        inkscape:pageshadow="2"
        inkscape:zoom="5.916495"
        inkscape:cx="61.898573"
        inkscape:cy="54.220135"
        inkscape:document-units="px"
        inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
        showgrid="false"
        inkscape:window-width="1280"
        inkscape:window-height="962"
        inkscape:window-x="-8"
        inkscape:window-y="-8"
        inkscape:window-maximized="1"/>
    <metadata
        id="metadata3038">
        <rdf:RDF>
            <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
                <dc:title></dc:title>
            </cc:Work>
        </rdf:RDF>
    </metadata>
    <g
        inkscape:label="Layer1"
        inkscape:groupmode="layer"
        id="layer1"
        transform="translate(0,-1004.3622)">
        <text
            xml:space="preserve"
            style="font-size:28px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Calibri;-inkscape-font-specification:Calibri"
            x="1.3270224e-007"
            y="1035.7983"
            id="text3049"
            sodipodi:linespacing="125%">
                <tspan
                    sodipodi:role="line"
                    id="tspan3051"
                    x="1.3270224e-007"
                    y="1035.7983">200m</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.I got the solution,This can be done by fwrite function as replied by sclarke81. I am able to change the font by using that code. I found your reply is informative,Thank you!